# Automation of DocuSign process on Opportunity

Tags: automation, docusign

I have installed DocuSign app from appExchange in Salesforce. Which I am using on Opportunity object. Currently, I go to the Opportunity record and then initiate Docusign process, wherein I select a a PDF/document and a recipient email address and click on "send" button.

However, I am looking at something, where the initiation of DocuSign process is done automatically. I mean to say that, when an Opportunity is created, a PDF/Document is supposed to sent to the email address of the Opportunity (taking it from its corresponding Account) without any clicks involved (send/attach).

Answer (score 3):

The people at DocuSign have created some documentation for this exact request.

[Reference Documentation](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/accessing-docusign-api-from-salesforcecom-to-send-contracts-for-esignatures)

> **Problem**
>
> You want to access the DocuSign API in your Force.com / Salesforce.com account in order to send an object with a single click of a button.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Before getting started you need to get a free Salesforce.com developer account at https://developer.force.com and a free DocuSign developer account at http://www.docusign.com/devcenter
>
> 1. Start out by adding DocuSign webservices to your authorized endpoints for your Salesforce.com developer account. To do this, go to Setup > Security > Remote Sites and add https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx.
> 2. Next, set up a Salesforce.com site so you can test rendering pages. There is plenty of documentation on how to get started with VisualForce, so we will leave it up to Salesforce.com to explain the best options there. For the purpose of this walkthrough you just need to have a site for testing. You can get to the screen below by clicking Setup > Develop > Sites. From there you can create a site label. Once the site is created all you need to do is make it active.
> 3. Now we need to create two pages; one for rendering a contract as a PDF and another that makes a web service call to DocuSign. We will start with the rendering page that we will call RenderContract (Note: the second page is set up in step 8). The code for the rendering page is fairly minimal. As you can see below, it just uses the standard Contract controller class and we are just rendering standard contract details with a couple of signature lines.
>
>    ```
>    <apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardController="Contract">
>        <apex:detail relatedList="true" title="true"/>
>        <div style='clear:right;margin-top:50px'>
>            <div style='float:right'>____________________________________</div>
>            <div style='float:right'>By:</div>
>        </div>    
>        <div style='clear:right;margin-top:50px'>
>            <div style='float:right'>____________________________________</div>
>            <div style='float:right'>Date Signed:</div>
>        </div>  
>    </apex:page>
>    ```
>
>    The page needs to be added to the site to ensure that you can access it for testing. You can accomplish that by going to the site detail and selecting Site VisualForce Pages. The other setting that has to be adjusted for testing is adding Contracts as something that is accessible from this site. To accomplish this go to Public Access Settings and edit the standard object permission.
> 4. In order to test the first page and other code in our sample, we will create a test Contract. For simplicity we are going to put a contact in the Customer Signed By field. At this point in time we have all the test data we need. You can note the Contract object ID in the URL https://na7.salesforce.com/800A0000000Q8ol And then use it to test the rendering page by plugging in the ID there: http://devcenter-demo-developer-edition.na7.force.com/apex/RenderContract?id=800A0000000Q8ol At this point you should be getting a PDF file.
> 5. In this step we are going to create a class to access the DocuSign API. For this walkthrough we are just going to get the sending WSDL, which can be found at https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/Schema/dsapi-send.wsdl. You should save the WSDL file to your desktop. (Note: For complete set of WSDL files please refer to documentation on DocuSign DevCenter.) Next go to the Apex Classes and select “Generate from WSDL”. When the class generator asks you to supply a class name, we suggest that you overwrite the class name with DocuSignAPI.
> 6. Using the new API endpoint, you can create a controller for the second page. In order to do this you need to go to Apex Classes again and create a new class. The code for the controller class is shown below:
>
>    ```
>    public with sharing class SendToDocuSignController {
>        private final Contract contract;
>
>        public String envelopeId {get;set;}
>        private String accountId = '';
>        private String userId = '';
>        private String password = '';
>        private String integratorsKey = '';
>        private String webServiceUrl 
>            = 'https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx';
>
>        public SendToDocuSignController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
>        {
>            this.contract = [select Id, CustomerSignedId, AccountId, ContractNumber 
>                from Contract where id = :controller.getRecord().Id];
>            envelopeId = 'Not sent yet';
>
>            SendNow();
>        }
>
>        public void SendNow()
>        {
>            DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap dsApiSend 
>                = new DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap();
>            dsApiSend.endpoint_x = webServiceUrl;
>
>            //Set Authentication
>            String auth = '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>'+ userId 
>                +'</Username><Password>' + password 
>                + '</Password><IntegratorKey>' + integratorsKey 
>                + '</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>';
>            System.debug('Setting authentication to: ' + auth);
>
>            dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
>            dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('X-DocuSign-Authentication', 
>                auth);
>
>            DocuSignAPI.Envelope envelope = new DocuSignAPI.Envelope();
>            envelope.Subject = 'Please Sign this Contract: ' 
>                + contract.ContractNumber;
>            envelope.EmailBlurb = 'This is my new eSignature service,'+ 
>                ' it allows me to get your signoff without having to fax, ' +
>                 'scan, retype, refile and wait forever';
>            envelope.AccountId  = accountId; 
>
>
>            // Render the contract
>            System.debug('Rendering the contract');
>            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/RenderContract');
>            pageRef.getParameters().put('id',contract.Id);
>            Blob pdfBlob = pageRef.getContent();     
>
>            // Document
>            DocuSignAPI.Document document = new DocuSignAPI.Document();
>            document.ID = 1;
>            document.pdfBytes = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdfBlob);
>            document.Name = 'Contract';
>            document.FileExtension = 'pdf';
>            envelope.Documents = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfDocument();
>            envelope.Documents.Document = new DocuSignAPI.Document[1];
>            envelope.Documents.Document[0] = document;
>
>            // Recipient
>            System.debug('getting the contact');
>            Contact contact = [SELECT email, FirstName, LastName 
>                from Contact where id = :contract.CustomerSignedId];
>
>            DocuSignAPI.Recipient recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
>            recipient.ID = 1;
>            recipient.Type_x = 'Signer';
>            recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
>            recipient.Email = contact.Email;
>            recipient.UserName = contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName;
>
>            // This setting seems required or you see the error:
>            // "The string '' is not a valid Boolean value. 
>            // at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToBoolean(String s)" 
>            recipient.RequireIDLookup = false;      
>
>            envelope.Recipients = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient();
>            envelope.Recipients.Recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient[1];
>            envelope.Recipients.Recipient[0] = recipient;
>
>            // Tab
>            DocuSignAPI.Tab tab1 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
>            tab1.Type_x = 'SignHere';
>            tab1.RecipientID = 1;
>            tab1.DocumentID = 1;
>            tab1.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
>            tab1.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'By:';
>
>
>            DocuSignAPI.Tab tab2 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
>            tab2.Type_x = 'DateSigned';
>            tab2.RecipientID = 1;
>            tab2.DocumentID = 1;
>            tab2.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
>            tab2.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'Date Signed:';
>
>            envelope.Tabs = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTab();
>            envelope.Tabs.Tab = new DocuSignAPI.Tab[2];
>            envelope.Tabs.Tab[0] = tab1;        
>            envelope.Tabs.Tab[1] = tab2;        
>
>            System.debug('Calling the API');
>            try {
>                DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus es 
>                    = dsApiSend.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
>                envelopeId = es.EnvelopeID;
>            } catch ( CalloutException e) {
>                System.debug('Exception - ' + e );
>                envelopeId = 'Exception - ' + e;
>            }          
>        }
>    }
>    ```
>
>    This might seem like a lot of code to understand, but the basics are pretty simple and you can see how a DocuSign envelope is constructed here: http://wiki.github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/code-walkthrough-create-and-send-envelope
> 7. In order to use DocuSign API, you need to retrieve your DocuSign API credentials. Go to https://demo.docusign.net, sign into your demo account, and then go to Preferences > API. There you will find these values:
>
>    - Integrator's Key: ZORO-a81ec71a-cb17-4af0-b1aa-9513115cbf02
>    - API UserName: 0e212ae6-1e12-40c1-8f5a-a57458ccaa63
>    - API Password:
>    - API Account ID: 736e7948-6861-4ef3-ae71-4c56603dc14f
>
>    Plug these values into the controller class.
> 8. The next step is to create the second page, which actually calls SendToDocuSign. You will add this page to the site and hook it up to the custom controller we just developed:
>
>    ```
>    <apex:page standardcontroller="Contract" extensions="SendToDocuSignController">
>        <h1>Your eSignature request is being sent to DocuSign API!</h1>
>        <hr/>
>        <apex:form >
>            <apex:commandButton value="Send Again!" action="{!SendNow}"/>
>        </apex:form>
>        <hr/>
>        <strong>The DocuSign EnvelopeId:</strong>{!envelopeId}<br/>
>    </apex:page>
>    ```
>
>    Now you should be able to test sending of the contract by calling the page with the same ID you used for testing the rendering page: http://devcenter-demo-developer-edition.na7.force.com/SendToDocuSign?id=800A0000000Q8ol
> 9. The last step is creating a custom button on the contract object that calls the sending page. Go to Setup > Customize > Contracts > Buttons and Links and create a New button. In the properties, select Detail Page Button and then add the URL with the Contract Id:
>
>    ```
>    /apex/SendToDocuSign?id={!Contract.Id}
>    ```
>
>    Add the button to the page layout for the Contract object. This lets your users click on the button to get their Contracts electronically signed! They don’t need to learn any other systems or follow complicated steps. The logic behind the button does all the work.

Comment: Thanks Double for descriptive direction for the DocuSign automation process. However, I got a question for you, which is: **Is there a way to customize the document that is being sent as an attachment to the corresponding email address**. If so, could you please let me know. 

Currently, the entire **Contract Detail page** is being sent as an attachment.

Comment: It won't let me comment, but just be aware that use of the Docusign API has a monthly fee associated with it -- they seem to bury that info.

Comment: Is there a way to do this so the docusign is automatically sent without clicking a button?

Answer (score 0):

Double A answer is really good and detail, however, I am not sure if that answer really apply for your question, as you can achieve exactly the same without the hassle of creating a class, for hence to create a test class, and more important the fact that you have to still push a button to achieve the action.

If you create a button with the following javascript you achieve the same without any apex code

```
var SourceID = "{!opp.Id}";
var LA = "0";
var DST = "XXXXX"; //This is the template id that you will only get from docusign portal
var OCO = "Send"; //this specify that the page is automatically send to avoid clicking send from that VF Page
window.open("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!opp.Id}&LA=0"+"&DST="+DST+"&OCO="+OCO, '_top');
```

However this doesnt answer your question as still the user need to click a button.